# can I use laravel 4 eloquent model or do I need to use db:query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Hi I am trying my first attempt to use ORM with Laravel. I have a big table from Drupal that I want to grab some records of and I need to join those with another table in Drupal to get the records that I care about manipulating.
Like so...

```
Node
----------------------------------------------------------
| Nid | type       | misc other stuff | N
==========================================================
| 1  | Programs    | Test Service    | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Programs    | Example Service | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Something else   | Another Service | 1       |
----------------------------------------------------------

Fields
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | title                         | NID | tag     |
==========================================================
| 1  | Blog Title 1                  | 1       | THER    |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | Blog Title 2                  | 2       | TES     |
----------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | Blog Title 3                  | 3       | ANOTHER |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get all the Nodes where type='Programs' and inner join those with all fields where NIDs are the same. Do I do that with an Eloquent ORM in app/model/node.php? Or a query builder statement $model=DB:table? what is the code for this? Or do I just do it in PHP?

Comment: You can use Eloquent easily to model this. Create relationships and work leveraging Eloquent models. However that's not enough info to tell you if it's going to make your life easier than using `Query\Builder` and manually create your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the ORM, but would have to override everything that makes it convenient and elegant.

Because you say you're trying to "manipulate" data in the fields table, it sounds like you're trying to update Drupal tables using something other than the Drupal field system. I would generally not recommend doing this—the Drupal field system is big, complicated, and special. There's a whole CMS to go with it.

You should move the data out of the old Drupal database and into your new database using seeds (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding).

Define a "drupal" database connection in your app/config/database.php, in addition to whatever you're using as a "default" connection for a new application. You can seed Eloquent models from an alternative connection in this manner:

```
<?php

// $nodes is an array of node table records inner joined to fields
$nodes = DB::connection('drupal')
    ->table('node')
    ->join('fields', 'node.nid', '=', 'fields.nid')
    ->get();
```

Pull the data out and put it in proper tables using Laravel migrations into normalized, ActiveRecord-style tables (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#creating-migrations).

Comment: Thanks that makes very much sense! Very nice solution and insight! I will re-evaluate how much I need to manipulate this data and possibly give this a try! I think I may need it for some other drupal tables either way so thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer query builder, it's more flexible

```
DB::table('Node')
->join('Fields', 'Fields.NID', '=', 'Node.Nid')
->where('type', 'Programs')
->get();
```

Comment: If I use a query like that is that considered creating a model? should I put the query into a /apps/models/programs.php file (by setting $program=<code>) or is that the wrong place for it?

Comment: no, you don't need to create a model, you can just place it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create two models in app/model (node.php and field.php) like this:

```
class Node extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
    protected $table = 'Node';

    public function fields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Field');
    }
}

class Field extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function node()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Node');
    }
}
```

Than you could do something like this:

```
$nodes = Node::with('fields')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();
```

You will get all your nodes with their relation where type is Programs.